# Ubuntu build dependencies - libblas

Tags: ubuntu, build, linker

I am trying to build a package which depends on BLAS (basic linear algebra subprograms). Currently, my Debian/control file looks like this:

Build-Depends: `gfortran, libblas3`

Depends: `gfortran, libblas3, ${shlibs:Depends}`

It builds without any errors on my computer. However, if I upload it to a PPA, build fails. I see from the log that `libblas3` is installed, and still, at the end I get:

```
ld --shared -o libXXX.so.X.Y  *.o -lblas -lc
ld: cannot find -lblas
```

Why does it not find libblas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *runtime* dependency (`Depends:`) is on `libblas3`. But your *build-time*
dependency (`Build-depends:`) is on the `libblas` development-package, which
is `libblas-dev`.

The linker flag `-lblas` directs the linker to find and link the library
referred to by `libblas.so` (shared library) or `libblas.a` (static library).
The runtime packgage `libblas3` will install a specifically versioned library,
e.g. `libblas.so.3.7.1`, but not `libblas.so`. The development package `libblas-dev`
will *not* install the specifically versioned library but *will* install `libblas.so`,
making it a symlink to the specifically versioned library.

There is a similar relationship between any library runtime package `libfoo` and its
development package `libfoo-dev`.